# Google ImportXML pull price from Box Store - Imported content is empty

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I am working on a spreadsheet to pull a few prices on common parts.  I am having difficulty with pulling a price from https://www.menards.com/main/p-1524638039424.htm

```
Google Sheets Error N/A - Imported content is empty.
```

If I understand console right, when I try to validate the xml, I get a return of `"[]"`. Xpather says the xpath to the price I need is

```
/html/body[@class='qb-oc-body-non-plp']/div[@class='wrap ']/div[@id='mainContent']/div[@id='page']/div/form[@id='itemForm']/div[@id='itemDetailPage']/div[2]/div[@id='item-header']/div[@class='itemCenterContent']/div[@id='price-div']/div[@id='sale-div']/span[@class='productPriceDescriptionPage']/div[@class='fontSize14']/span[@class='EDLP fontSize16 fontBold alignRight']
```

Inspect element copy xpath tells me `//*[@id="sale-div"]/span/div[1]/span[2]`

I am concatenating these two values in my spreadsheet with the error
https://www.menards.com/main/p-1524638039424.htm

`//*[@id="sale-div"]/span/div[1]/span[2]/text()`

Is there anyway to pull the price on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this won't be possible:

[image]

Comment: Well, shoot.  Thank you.  I learned something from you on how to test this for the next time I have an issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Could there be another way to automate my price list process?

Comment: try using some other site (if there is such)